# VBA Why the if function does not filter my data by specific phrases

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a problem with my code. I would like to display a specific email and save email.bodys in excel file filtering by a specific phrase (contained in the mails' body). The if function **doesn't work** in the below code. It's downloading all emails from my box.

Could you point me what's wrong?

```
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Set o = New Outlook.Application

Dim ons As Outlook.Folder
Set ons = o.GetNamespace("mapi")

Dim myfol As Outlook.Folder
Set myfol = ons.getdefaulfolder(olFolderDrafts)

Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set omail = o.CreateItem(oimailItem)

Dim r As Long
r = 2
For Each omail In myflo.Items

    If omail.Body = "specific text" Then
        omail.Display
        Cells(r, 1).Value = omail.Body
        r = r + 1
    End If
Next omail
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Note that you have at least two undeclared variables (`oimailItem` and `myflo`) which can be avoided by using `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.  Beyond that, "it doesn't work" doesn't give any information for others to help you with; perhaps you could expand?  Also, see how to create a [mcve] and what's on-topic at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the InStr function to check whether the body of the email contains a specific text...

```
If InStr(1, omail.Body, "specific text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

For a case-sensitive search, replace vbTextCompare with vbBinaryCompare.

Comment: The OP indicates "downloading all emails from my box" (Inbox?) when referencing "olFolderDrafts". You might support the request for an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score -1):

According to the quote you asked, "complete emails from my box" (Inbox?) When referencing 'olFolderDrafts' "
You need to add the ID of the mail you want to download.